# Buzzing sound from speakers when scrolling or mouse movement in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: 18.04, sound

I get a low frequency, low volume buzzing sound from my speakers while scrolling, moving the mouse or holding down a key (Type-a-Matic) while using Chrome or Firefox. 
This does not happen on other operating systems on the same machine.
No sound when no screen movement. 
The buzzing also occurs on the current Google screen with the Beethoven cartoon, even when it's not playing!

If no mouse/keyboard/scrolling/screen activity, no buzz.

This is an old Dell machine running Ubuntu 18.04.02.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same behavior on my PC right now, and I know exactly why. It is caused by interference generated by my Steinberg UR-44 USB Audio Interface. If I unplug it, the problem vanishes and resumes immediately when it is reconnected.

In fact. I found that replacing the USB cable itself made it possible to reconnect the audio interface without the noise, solving the problem.

Although this may or may not work for you, if you have external USB devices or other equipment plugged into your machine. It might be worthwhile to disconnect them and see if the sounds persist or not. If they stop, plug each item back in one at a time and see what happens.

Hopefully this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Driver and hardware compatibility issue. I'd try a older version of ubuntu depending on how old your comp really is.  Thought though, look at your sound settings first, you may have the mic turned up... :) there is a cool terminal command to show all your sound settings called alsa mixer.
This link is a how to get and use alsa mixer.
https://www.maketecheasier.com/alsa-utilities-manage-linux-audio-command-line/

simple is open terminal and type or paste the following
sudo apt install alsa-utils

[Attached is a pic of alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2JMI.png)

This explains how to update your alsa (audio) and at the top explains legacy audio vs more recent audio...

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by my KVM switch. The audio from the computer
to the speakers went through my KVM switch.
Plugging the speakers directly into the computer solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing a similar issue in Chromium and Firefox, In my case, it's happening in Ubuntu 20.04, not 18.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

In my opinion, the noises resemble those of a hard disk being accessed - however, my laptop has an SSD.

Taking advice from:

https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/jqa824/well_moving_my_mouse_cursor_on_firefox_creates_a/gblyael/

I've disabled hardware acceleration in both browsers. This seems to have significantly mitigated (though not fully fixed) the problem in Chromium. It has made little difference in Firefox.

The problem seems to be reduced even further by using a mouse instead of the touchpad. I've tested this with a USB 2.0 mouse.

I've noticed with Chromium that even after disabling hardware acceleration, I can still provoke the problem by scrolling the mouse over several hyperlinks in succession. This in turn makes me wonder whether the links changing colour, or the URLs appearing in the grey boxes at the bottom of the screen, might be related.

In case it's relevant, I'm using MATE Desktop, and I haven't tested with any other GUIs.